# Git push issue, added large file by mistake , cant remove it from the commit

Tags: git, github

i just pushed a large file by mistake , then i got an error like

```
Enumerating objects: 48, done.
Counting objects: 100% (48/48), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32/32), 549.93 MiB | 7.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 32 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (18/18), completed with 15 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 18cdd4c550929262ddff914e24f2f504d9bdd73ff8e7f71f1a60cef087522dd0
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File vendor.zip is 558.48 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Then i removed the file from the direcotry , and the  tried to push again.

But getting the same issue.

I tried to change the branch  also , but no way, still getting the same error, tried some solutions from the web, that also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove the file from the tracked files.

```
git rm —cached path/to/file
```

Make sure afterwards you add the file to `.gitignore` to avoid issues in the future.

Comment: I run this command, but i got another issue like "fatal: pathspec 'vendor.zip' did not match any files" .